# Simulink 3dof block error: initial velocity cannot be set to zero

Tags: simulink

New Simulink user here. I am using a 3DOF box to simulate a rocket launch. When I try to modify the block parameters, it does not let me set the initial velocity as 0. It displays an error saying the parameter only supports positive value. (see [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px2b2.png)) How can this be corrected?

Cheers

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. A quick fix that I do is set some number insanely close to zero like, 0.00000000001. It'll mitigate the problem, but not totally answer your question. Hoping you figured out the answer, and if so please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket to Matlab, apparently it is a bug, and will be fixed tomorrow with the 2022a Matlab release.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).